# Possible to prompt for username and password instead of hardcoding in pip.ini file?

Tags: python, security, pip, artifactory

My org has an instance of Artifactory where Python packages are to be installed from. I need to point `pip` to our internal Artifactory endpoint so I can develop locally with packages installed from here.

**After some research, I found I needed to:**

1. Create a `pip.ini` file in one of the locations shown after running `pip config -v list`
2. To this new `pip.ini` file, add:

```
[global]
index-url = https://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/pypi/python/simple
```

**How do I keep my Username and Password out of the URL above?**

I'd rather be prompted or some other method than storing this info in plaintext in a config file.

Answer (score 1):

if you remove `<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@` from the url, you will be prompted for username password.

```html
[global]
index-url = https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/pypi/python/simple
```